# How Can I Use Some Text Boxes in One Operation?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, tabcontrol

I am a new C# user. Recently I'm Working On My New Project. That's a kind of Tabbed NotePad Like Notepad++!

Actually, It has a Main `TabControl` Filled All the form and also it has a default `TabPage` Called "New Text" that it contains a `TextBox`(RichTextBox). 
My form has a Docked `panel` at the top Too! And it contains some `PictureBoxes`  *This is not the point of topic so As I told you(or didn't!) These `PictureBoxes` Are able to do Lots of Things :D
For instance, Clicking On the PicFont Will Change The selected Text's Font. 
And The Code Is:

```
    private void PicFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
    richtextBox1.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
}
```

On the Other Hand, I have another `Picture Box` That Adds A new `Tab Page` with a `TextBox` Inside To my `Tab Control`. With This Code:

```
private void P_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Text"); 
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp); 
    RichTextBox tb = new RichTextBox(); 
    tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
    tb.Multiline = true; 
    tb.WordWrap = false; 
    tp.Controls.Add(tb); 
}
```

But These Are Not my problem! I want This Void (PicFont_Click) To work For Other `TextBoxes` Too, Not Only `RichTextBox1` !!
Tnx A million…

Comment: Hmmm... you wrote 90% of your question not about your question. Can you edit your post to focus on your question and what you've tried so far to solve it?

Comment: Have e.g. a flag or a checkbox to let the user choose and before creating a control test to see which control was chosen. Still the usefulness from a user's standpoint seems dubious..

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a collection of the RichTextBoxes that shall be affected by the PicFont method. On `P_Click`, add the new RichTextBox to this collection. In `PicFont_Click`, loop over all affected RichTextBoxes and set the font.

Remember to remove the RichTextBox from this collection when its tab is closed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    private IList<RichTextBox> AffectedBoxes { get; set; }

    public Form1() {
        // List must be initialized before we can add to it
        AffectedBoxes = new List<RichTextBox>();
        // other stuff ...
    }

    private void P_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // ...

        RichTextBox tb = new RichTextBox(); 
        AffectedBoxes.Add(tb); // remember that we have to handle this RichTextBox 

        // ...
    } 

    private void PicFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        fontDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // loop over all affected boxes
        foreach (var box in AffectedBoxes) {
            box.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It Works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking for it to find the selected tab, then change the selected text in only the `RichTextBox` on that tab?

```
private void PicFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
    var r = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.FirstOrDefault(a => a is RichTextBox) as RichTextBox;
    if (r != null) 
        r.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but .FirstOrDefault()  doesn't work.